# log4net - multiple instances - one in global.asax and another in .net app itself

Tags: asp.net, .net, log4net

I have modified global.asax to user log4net to log all requests and responses to an underlying webservice.

The webservice also uses log4net, and the two instances are not working independently of each other.

Both instances must use their own config file, as they log to different locations.

Is it possible to have two completely separate instances of log4net running, one in global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this required setup within a single configuration file.
Just use dedicated `logger` instances, each having its own `appender` instance(s), which output to a separate location.

In your **webservice**, use a logger named eg. `WebServiceLogger`.

```
log4net.ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("WebServiceLogger");`
```

Configure this logger to use an appender named eg. `WebServiceAppender`
and give it its own output file eg. `c:\logs\webservice.log`.
The setting `additivity=false` ensures that this logger will not use any inherited default/root appenders.

```
<logger name="WebServiceLogger" additivity="false">        
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="WebServiceAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="WebServiceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\logs\webservice.log" />
    <!-- other settings go here -->
</appender>
```

Configure **Global.asax** in a similar way.

```
log4net.ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("GlobalAsaxLogger");

<logger name="GlobalAsaxLogger" additivity="false">        
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="GlobalAsaxAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="GlobalAsaxAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\logs\globalasax.log" />
    <!-- other settings go here -->
</appender>
```

Any other declared loggers will use the `root` logger, here writing to the appender with name `GeneralAppender`.

---

Full configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <logger name="WebServiceLogger" additivity="false">        
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="WebServiceAppender" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="WebServiceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="c:\logs\webservice.log" />
        <!-- other settings go here -->
    </appender>

    <logger name="GlobalAsaxLogger" additivity="false">        
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="GlobalAsaxAppender" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="GlobalAsaxAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="c:\logs\webservice.log" />
        <!-- other settings go here -->
    </appender>

    <appender name="GeneralAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="c:\logs\general.log" />
        <!-- other settings go here -->
    </appender>

    <root>                
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```